# optimize a string query with pandas. large data

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, indexing

I have a dataframe data, which has close to 4 millions rows. It is a list of cities on the world. I need to query the city name as fast as possible.

I found out that one with 346ms via indexing the city name:

> d2=data.set_index("city",inplace=False)
>
> timeit d2.loc[['PARIS']]
>
> 1 loop, best of 3: 346 ms per loop

This is still much too slow. I wonder if with group-by I could achieve faster query (how to do such a query). Each city has around 10 rows in the dataframe (duplicate city).
I searched several days and could not find a clear solution on the internet

thank you

Comment: Any feedback on the posted solutions?

Comment: @Divakar need to test your solution with Numpy, but my question was for Pandas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Paris'+str(i),i] for i in range(100000)]*10,columns=['city','value'])
```

**Baseline**

```
df2 = df.set_index('city')
%timeit df2.loc[['Paris9999']]
10 loops, best of 3: 45.6 ms per loop
```

**Solution**

Using a lookup dict and then use iloc:

```
idx_dict = df.groupby(by='city').apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist()).to_dict()

%timeit df.iloc[d['Paris9999']]
1000 loops, best of 3: 432 µs per loop
```

It seems this approach is almost 100 times faster than the baseline.

**Comparing to other approaches:**

```
%timeit df2[df2.index.values=="Paris9999"]
100 loops, best of 3: 16.7 ms per loop

%timeit full_array_based(df2, "Paris9999")
10 loops, best of 3: 19.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: looks the best solution. I may have a few questions tomorrow before I accept your answer

Comment: the canonical method here is ``df.groupby('city').get_group()``. Keep in mind that the *first* time you do a lookup the hashtable is created (same with indexing), subsequent indexing is constant time.

Comment: I did not try the numpy version from Divakar, as Allen solution solved my problem

Comment: Test it on large dataset(~11M lines), Prestoring indice into dict or set is faster than simple query! Very good answer

Answer (score 1):

Working with the array data for the index, comparing against the needed index and then using the mask from the comparison might be one option when looking for performance. A sample case might make things clear.

1) Input dataframes :

```
In [591]: df
Out[591]: 
    city  population
0  Delhi        1000
1  Paris          56
2     NY          89
3  Paris          36
4  Delhi         300
5  Paris          52
6  Paris          34
7  Delhi          40
8     NY          89
9  Delhi         450

In [592]: d2 = df.set_index("city",inplace=False)

In [593]: d2
Out[593]: 
       population
city             
Delhi        1000
Paris          56
NY             89
Paris          36
Delhi         300
Paris          52
Paris          34
Delhi          40
NY             89
Delhi         450
```

2) Indexing with `.loc` :

```
In [594]: d2.loc[['Paris']]
Out[594]: 
       population
city             
Paris          56
Paris          36
Paris          52
Paris          34
```

3) Use mask based indexing :

```
In [595]: d2[d2.index.values=="Paris"]
Out[595]: 
       population
city             
Paris          56
Paris          36
Paris          52
Paris          34
```

4) Finally timings :

```
In [596]: %timeit d2.loc[['Paris']]
1000 loops, best of 3: 475 µs per loop

In [597]: %timeit d2[d2.index.values=="Paris"]
10000 loops, best of 3: 156 µs per loop
```

---

**Further boost**

Going further with using array data, we can extract the entire input dataframe as array and index into it. Thus, an implementation using that philosophy would look something like this -

```
def full_array_based(d2, indexval):
    df0 = pd.DataFrame(d2.values[d2.index.values==indexval])
    df0.index = [indexval]*df0.shape[0]
    df0.columns = d2.columns
    return df0
```

Sample run and timings -

```
In [635]: full_array_based(d2, "Paris")
Out[635]: 
       population
Paris          56
Paris          36
Paris          52
Paris          34

In [636]: %timeit full_array_based(d2, "Paris")
10000 loops, best of 3: 146 µs per loop
```

Comment: your second method is very efficient with my d2 (4 millions rows):
timeit d2[d2.index.values=='GRENOBLE_CENTRE_d2']
10 loops, best of 3: 140 ms per loop


But full_array_based gets highly slow result (?)

timeit full_array_based(d2,'GRENOBLE_CENTRE_d2')
1 loop, best of 3: 2.26 s per loop

Comment: @laurentngu Added another solution [**`here`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44064966/3293881) that uses pre-processing to setup a dict for later indexing. Check that out too!

Answer (score 1):

If we are allowed to pre-process to setup a dictonary that could be indexed for extracting `city` string based data extraction from the input dataframe, here's one solution using NumPy to do so -

```
def indexed_dict_numpy(df):
    cs = df.city.values.astype(str)
    sidx = cs.argsort()
    scs = cs[sidx]    
    idx = np.concatenate(( [0], np.flatnonzero(scs[1:] != scs[:-1])+1, [cs.size]))
    return {n:sidx[i:j] for n,i,j in zip(cs[sidx[idx[:-1]]], idx[:-1], idx[1:])}
```

Sample run -

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
    city  population
0  Delhi        1000
1  Paris          56
2     NY          89
3  Paris          36
4  Delhi         300
5  Paris          52
6  Paris          34
7  Delhi          40
8     NY          89
9  Delhi         450

In [11]: dict1 = indexed_dict_numpy(df)

In [12]: df.iloc[dict1['Paris']]
Out[12]: 
    city  population
1  Paris          56
3  Paris          36
5  Paris          52
6  Paris          34
```

Runtime test against [`@Allen's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44059256/3293881) to setup a similar dictionary with 4 Mil rows -

```
In [43]: # Setup 4 miliion rows of df
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Paris'+str(i),i] for i in range(400000)]*10,\
    ...:                                                 columns=['city','value'])
    ...: np.random.shuffle(df.values)
    ...: 

In [44]: %timeit df.groupby(by='city').apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist()).to_dict()
1 loops, best of 3: 2.01 s per loop

In [45]: %timeit indexed_dict_numpy(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop
```